# Trying to ensure that method checks for alpha and hyphen characters in Swift

Tags: ios, regex, swift, nsstring

I have a method that is meant to return a boolean value of true if a string value that it receives contains any combination of either upper/lowercase characters or a hyphen, and returns false if it contains any numbers, or special characters (i.e. contains anything outside of the above character set).  I have the following method which unfortunately is not doing that:

```
let alphaCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-"

        if self.isNameValid("joe-bYlow") {
            print("correct")
        } //passes

        if self.isNameValid("YYYYY") {
            print("correct")
        } //passes

        if self.isNameValid("8888ja;sdf") {
            print ("wrong")
        } //fails i.e. it prints "wrong"

        if self.isNameValid("__^&^%%%jdjjd") {
            print ("wrong")
        } //fails i.e. it prints "wrong"

        if self.isNameValid("9999") {
            print("also wrong")
        } //passes

        if self.isNameValid("blahBlah8") {
            print("wrong")
        } //fails i.e. it prints "wrong"

        if self.isNameValid("Frank") {
            print("correct")
        } //passes

    func isNameValid(name: String) -> Bool {
        let characterSetAllowed = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: alphaCharacters)
        if let _ = name.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(characterSetAllowed, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

Can anyone see what it is I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solution is very close to being correct. The logic in your method is checking if **ANY** character in the name is in alpha characters.

In the case of the string `__^&^%%%jdjjd`, `rangeOfCharacterFromSet` is returning the range of the first character it finds in the set. So it returns the range `{8, 1}` for the first `j`.

So how do we check for **ALL** characters in the string? You could loop through every character but that seems like a lot of work.

My solution would be to get the set of characters that you don't want then check that none of the characters are in that set.

```
func isNameValid(name: String) -> Bool {
    let characterSetNotAllowed = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: alphaCharacters).invertedSet
    if let _ = name.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(characterSetNotAllowed, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Also, thanks for putting your code in a form that could be easily put into a Playground to show the issue. It made it really easy to find the cause.

Comment: Thanks very much for your time, and help.  Your solution worked!